# Top questions page is showing 6 months old question without any reason

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users, unanswered-questions, community-user

I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401116/my-wcf-service-works-fine-on-a-windows-7-enterprise-machine-but-fails-when-hosted) on Top questions page (SO home page). The question shows that there was some activity today by [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) but the question itself nor the answer have any modification. By reading Community user's "About Me" I guess it is some algorithm to resurrect unanswered questions. Is it really needed to do this with a questions asked by [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410185/ram) with reputation 1 who didn't visit SO since asking that question (so he can hardly accept any answer)?

Also the question is partially answered by the owner but it cannot be detected by automatic process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see our definition of "answered"

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

it is quite strict.

There is a process that pings (n) questions per hour to churn the sediment, so we can find both treasures and trash.

In this case, I like that the asker came back and answered his own question so I upvoted it, as I typically do in such cases.. now it is no longer unanswered and the asker gets some rep. Also, future visitors who find that question will see there is an answer that has been vetted by at least two human beings.